# Merging dataframes of different lenghts in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[My firat data frame is df_movieid_genre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8nxS.png)

[Second data frame is df_fraction_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVBAO.png)

I need to join them based on movieID. Inner or outer join is not gonna work because the df_fraction_data contains repetition of the movie_ids. I guess for loop can be used but I am a beginner and having a problem in doing so. Thanks in advance..  [I need something like this ( just a small example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBo7C.png)

Comment: You can join those even with the duplicate `movie_ids` but the resulting frame will be huge as i assume there are many duplicates for each `movie_id` inside the `df_fraction`. Do you want to aggregate the information in the df_fraction table before joining? Something like the average rating per `movie_id` or something. When you say inner or out joins do not work. Did you try ? Did it give you any issues? It should work with duplicates

Comment: A join will be enough for this case, even with duplicates. Try to include part of your data or code in this or in your next question. No just a link to the image, that makes it difficult to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.merge(left=df_movieid_genre, right=df_fraction_data, on=['Movie_Id'], how='inner')
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. I tried the same code but I kept but i kept movieID_genre in right instead of left. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) df_fraction with movie_id and access each group and attach the row with that movie_id.

```py
import pandas as pd

def merger(df,df2):
    row_to_be_merge = df2[ df2.index[ df2['Movie_id']==df.name][0] ]   

    df['Genre'],df['Movie_name'] = row_to_be_merge[['Genre','Movie_name']]

    return df

merged_df = df_fraction.group_by('Movie_id').apply(merger, df2 = df_movieid_genre)
```

> [*apply*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) will run *merger* on each group dataframe and *merger* function will concat *Genre* and *Movie_name* row value for that *movie_id* from *df_movieid_genre* dataframe for each row of that group. Hope it helps :)